# Add informative lines in baroplots in a for loop

Tags: r

I have two data.frames:

> ```
>  DF1
> Samples       CCL10        CXCR9        GUSP1
>    a            23           87           09      
>    b            21           15           65    
>    c             5            4           12 
>    d            43           56            1
>   ....         ....         .....        ......
> ```

> ```
> DF2
> Statistics    CCL10        CXCR9        GUSP1
> Mean           14            45           43
>  SD             3             7           20
> ```

The values reported are simulated with respect to the real data I have.
I would like to create bar plots one for each column of DF1 and for each barplot I would like to add the corresponding horizontal lines of Mean and SD in DF2.

I tried the following:

```
for (i in 2:ncol(DF1)  {
        for (j in 2:ncol(DF2)){
            barplot(DF1[,i], ylab = "Measure",  main = paste(names(DF1[i]))) 
            abline(h=DF2[j][1,], col = "Red")
            abline(h=DF2[j][2,], col = "blue")
          }
      }
```

it does not work in the sense that it repeats many times the plots.
Could you help me to figure out where I'm wrong?
Moreover is there a way to set, for each barplot the y-ranges (not manually because I have 50 barplots) because some bars are out of the range of automatically generated y-axis limits?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you trying with `ggplot2` and `tidyverse` functions. It is more practical reshaping the datatsets to long, merging them and skecth the plot using facets for each variable. Here a code as option for you:

```
library(tidyverse)
#Code
DF1 %>%
  pivot_longer(-Samples) %>%
  left_join(
    DF2 %>% pivot_longer(-Statistics) %>% rename(Stat=value)
  ) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from=Statistics,values_from=Stat) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=Samples,y=value))+
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity',fill='magenta',color='black')+
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept = Mean),lty='dashed',color='red')+
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept = SD),lty='dashed',color='blue')+
  facet_wrap(.~name,scales = 'free')
```

Output:

[image]

Some data used:

```
#Data 1
DF1 <- structure(list(Samples = c("a", "b", "c", "d"), Value1 = c(23L, 
21L, 5L, 43L), Value2 = c(87L, 15L, 4L, 56L), Value3 = c(9L, 
65L, 12L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))

#Data 2
DF2 <- structure(list(Statistics = c("Mean", "SD"), Value1 = c(14L, 
3L), Value2 = c(45L, 7L), Value3 = c(43L, 20L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))
```

Try this modification with a list:

```
library(tidyverse)
#Data
DataOut <- DF1 %>%
  pivot_longer(-Samples) %>%
  left_join(
    DF2 %>% pivot_longer(-Statistics) %>% rename(Stat=value)
  ) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from=Statistics,values_from=Stat)
#Split by variable
List <- split(DataOut,DataOut$name)
#Function for plots
myplotfun <- function(x)
{
  G <- ggplot(data=x,aes(x=Samples,y=value))+
    geom_bar(stat = 'identity',fill='magenta',color='black')+
    geom_hline(aes(yintercept = Mean),lty='dashed',color='red')+
    geom_hline(aes(yintercept = SD),lty='dashed',color='blue')+
    facet_wrap(.~name,scales = 'free')
  return(G)
}
#Apply
Lplots <- lapply(List,myplotfun)
#Export
pdf('Myreport.pdf',width = 14)
for(i in c(1:length(Lplots)))
{
  plot(Lplots[[i]])
}
dev.off()
```

The output in pdf file will show a slide per variable like this:

[image]

Comment: Thank you duck for your help. It does not work because to simplify I wrote here the column names as Value* but the real column names are the ones you will see after my editing and I think this is the reason why it does not work. How your code will become with real column names? Thank you in advance. PS: to plot all bar plots in a single pdf I usually run a for loop. Is it possible to include a for loop to save all plots in a single pdf? Thank you in advance

Comment: @Elb Let me adjust the code for what you want using the new data!

Comment: @Elb I have added an update for what you want using the new data. Let me know if that works!